# Adding ngx-bootstrap directives to component HTML renders it blank

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, ngx-bootstrap

I was trying out ngx-bootstrap for some dropdowns, but each time I incorporate one of the new directives into my component's HTML, it just all disappears...

I have imported the dropdown module into my app module by adding `BsDropdownModule.forRoot()` to the imports array.

The following code yields a blank page (or rather, component section):

```html
<h1>Hello world!</h1>

<div class="btn-group" dropdown>
  <button id="button-basic" dropdownToggle type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle"
    aria-controls="dropdown-basic">
    Button dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul id="dropdown-basic" *dropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="button-basic">
    <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li class="divider dropdown-divider"></li>
    <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

But if I remove all those dropdown directives (`dropdown` on that `btn-group`, `dropdownToggle` and `*dropdownMenu`), it displays the header, a styled albeit non-functional dropdown button.

Any idea what might be causing such strange behavior?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you also include the styling?

Comment: I have added the `bootstrap.min.css` stylesheet in my `angular.json`, but the styling doesn't seem to be the problem. Like I said, if I don't use the ngx-bootstrap directives, the drodown button gets correctly rendered and styled, yet doesn't do anything.